# Estimating sum of off-diagonals in covariance matrix with known diagonal

Tags: maximum-likelihood, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

Assume we have $n$ samples from $\mathbf{X}\ \sim\ \mathcal{N}_k(\boldsymbol 0,\, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$ where elements of $\boldsymbol\Sigma_{k \times k} = [ \Sigma]_{ij}$ are the covariance matrix.

Is there a way to estimate the sum of the off-diagonals directly, knowing the diagonal variance terms? (Without necessarily estimating all elements individually)

> Example: For $k=3$ if  $\begin{pmatrix}  X_1 \\  X_2 \\ X_3 \end{pmatrix}  \sim
>  \mathcal{N} \left( \begin{pmatrix}  0 \\  0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ,
>  \begin{pmatrix}  10 & 5 & 3 \\  5 & 20 & 2 \\  3 & 2 & 30 \\
>  \end{pmatrix} \right) $ we would know
> $\operatorname{Var}{(X)}=\{10,20,30\}$ and wish to estimate
> $S=5+3+2=10$ without necessarily having to estimate each term
> individually.

For bivariate normal and known variances $\{\sigma^2_1,\sigma^2_2\}$, the maximum likelihood estimate of the unknown off-diagonal covariance term is equivalent to solving the root to a cubic polynomial.

Another option is to add the elements of the random vector; this would produce univariate normal distribution with mean 0 and variance  $T+2\,S$  (T for trace). From there an estimate of $S$ can be determined using MLE readily. However, this uses only the trace - which is the sum of the known variance values - and not the individual values themselves. For bivariate normal this is using information of $\sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2 =T$ as oppose to the cubic expression knowing both $\{\sigma^2_1,\sigma^2_2\}$ individually.

Comment: In your example with known variances there still remains 3 free parameters : how can we find these with a single equation?

Comment: @Yves If the variances were unknown the entire k^2 matrix can be estimated by the sample covariance formula. I suspect (but don't know) there may another formula or algorithm when restricted to known variance diagonal. If so, that would work to answer the question, but it may be possible (and easier) to go directly to estimating the sum.